# TypeScript Parameters<T> removes generic parameters of T

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to create a fluent API that is composed of non-fluent functions. For example I have generic functions of the form `<...>(...args: any[]) => T` and I want to transform each function to the form `<...>(...args: any[]) => FluentInterface` while maintaining the generic arguments. Inferring the arguments yields a function of form `(...args: any[]) => FluentInterface` loosing the generic arguments of the function.

```js
type A = {
  kind: "A";
  a: string;
};

type B = {
  kind: "B";
  b: string;
};

type Obj = {
  kind: string;
};

type All = A | B;

export type WithKind<T extends Obj, K extends T["kind"]> = T extends {
  kind: K;
}
  ? T
  : never;

class CreateStep {
  create<K extends All["kind"]>(
    kind: K,
    data: Omit<WithKind<All, K>, "kind">
  ): WithKind<All, K> {
    return { ...data, kind } as WithKind<All, K>;
  }
}

interface FluentFactory {
  // <K extends "A" | "B">(kind: K, data: Omit<WithKind<A, K> | WithKind<B, K>, "kind">) => WithKind<A, K> | WithKind<B, K>
  create: CreateStep["create"];

  // (kind: "A" | "B", data: Omit<A | B, "kind">) => FluentFactory
  // generic parameters lost so the tie between kind and data is lost.
  createFluent: CreateStep["create"] extends (...arg: infer A) => any
    ? (...a: A) => FluentFactory
    : never;
}

const inst: FluentFactory = {} as FluentFactory;
inst.create("A", { a: "a" });
// as a result the fluent method no longer uses kind to discriminate
// so data is A | B 
inst.createFluent("A", {}).createFluent("B", {});
```

Comment: You can't do this purely at the type level (see [ms/TS#43731](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43731)) ; the closest you can get is to drop to the value level and use [support for higher order generic inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvoY3w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is one option I am exploring. @jcalz has a solution as well but this may be more appropriate for my use case.

```js
class CreateStep<F = false> {
  create<K extends All["kind"]>(
    kind: K,
    data: Omit<WithKind<All, K>, "kind">
  ): F extends false ? WithKind<All, K> : F {
    return { ...data, kind } as any;
  }
}

interface FluentFactory {
  create: CreateStep["create"];

  createFluent: CreateStep<FluentFactory>["create"];
}

const inst: FluentFactory = {} as FluentFactory;
inst.create("A", { a: "a" }).a;
inst.createFluent("A", { a: "" }).createFluent("B", { b: "" });
```

Comment: Hmm, so you've refactored `CreateStep` itself? That works (although I would have thought making such changes was out of scope, given the question as asked)... but you might want to flesh this answer out to actually explain it, for future readers.

Comment: @jcalz I have control of the contract for CreateStep.create. I just need a simple contract. The only problem with my proposal above is that CreateStep.create's return value has to be cast to `any` or `F extends false? WithKind<All,K> : F` Although, as I look closer this may not work for my scenario because I am using AsynGenerator so I don't have direct access to the return type. I may need to use your solution.

Comment: Either way, you should probably [edit] to explain it in the answer itself. Comments are ephemeral.

Comment: Although instead of create an instance of CreateStep I'll try `(instance: InstanceType<S>) => any`. And yes, I'll add the solution if this works.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you should explain the current answer even if you end up using my solution.  If you're going to post an answer with my solution I'd prefer if you let me do that, unless you have some compelling reason why it's more appropriate for you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a modified version of @jcalz approach. But in my real scenario `FluentFactory` is a `class` instead of an `interface`

```js
function replaceFnRet<
  C extends new (...a: any[]) => any,
  I extends InstanceType<C>,
  A extends any[],
  RC extends new (...a: any[]) => any,
  R = InstanceType<RC>
>(c: C, f: (i: I) => (...a: A) => any, r: RC): (...a: A) => R {
  return null!;
}

class FluentFactory {
    create: CreateStep["create"];
    createFluent: replaceFnRet(CreateStep, i=> i.create, FluentFactory);
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really work, though.  There's no `replaceFnRet` in your code. It exists only in a comment I made, and comments are ephemeral, they can go away at any time.  Answers should be standalone and explain what they do.  And, uh, should I even bother posting my own answer? You seem to have not responded to any of my questions or suggestions about my doing so.

Comment: @jcalz I ended up going a completely different route however your solution is the correct answer for this question. If you would like to post that solution I can mark it as the answer.